# Java - is there any reason to check if a singleton is null twice?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, singleton

I have come across some code, where the developer is constantly checking if the singleton is null twice with a nested if - like in the code below:

```
private static processManager singleton = null;
```

...

```
public synchronized static processManager getInsatnce() throws Exception {

    if(singleton == null) {
      if(singleton == null){
             singleton = new processManager();
       }
     }
     return singleton
}
```

I cannot see any reason why this might be, but there are numerous instances in the code, so thought there might be a reason?

Comment: It looks like a failed attempt at two-phase locking. That could've made sense if the innermost `if` statement was in a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at Marko's answer. Interesting!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)

Answer (score 16):

Your code doesn't demonstrate the case properly. This stems from the *double-checked* idiom, where it does make sense:

```
// Double-check idiom for lazy initialization of instance fields.
private volatile FieldType field;
FieldType getField() {
    FieldType result = field;
    if (result == null) { // First check (no locking)
        synchronized(this) {
            result = field;
            if (result == null) // Second check (with locking)
                field = result = computeFieldValue();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Read about it [over here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/bloch-effective-08-qa-140880.html).

Be careful to note that this idiom is a good choice only for **instance** fields. In your question you have a `static` field, for which case a much simpler idiom is the primary choice: the *lazy initialion holder class* idiom:

```
// Lazy initialization holder class idiom for static fields
private static class FieldHolder {
    static final FieldType field = computeFieldValue();
}
static FieldType getField() { return FieldHolder.field; }
```

Answer (score 6):

It is a failed attempt to achieve [**Double Checked Locking Idiom**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). The first `null` check is to see if the instance is already created and if it is `not null` then just return the instance already created.

But the condition check is a *check-then-act* situation and is **not thread safe**, so there is a possibility that two or more threads will see the value as `null` and create two instances of *singleton* and thats *doubleton* or maybe *ManyTon*.

So we use `synchronized` so that only one thread enters that block and only a single instance is created.

Comment: Excellent explanation on Double Checked Locking Idiom.

Comment: So because the method is synchronized, there is presumably no need to use double  checked locking?

Comment: Keeping the method singleton creates a happens before relationship and so it is ok to have only a single null check. NOTE: This method will perform badly because it locks the class. So it is better not to keep the method synchronized but use the technique that has already been mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're referring to [Double Checked Locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking). This pattern allows you to avoid synchronization when it is not needed.

You code should be

```
private static volatile ProcessManager singleton = null;

public static ProcessManager getInstance() throws Exception {

    if (singleton == null) {
        synchronized (MyClass.class) {
            if (singleton == null) {
                singleton = new ProcessManager();
            }
        }
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

So you see we only sync when we have checked that the singleton is not null, we then recheck just in case someone has already begun to build it. Note that for this to work, the singleton **must be** `volatile`. [Here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) is an article that explains the subtle issue that arises, if you forget the `volatile`.

In your case, where the method is synchronized, you are right. There is no point in checking twice.

Answer (score 0):

This does not make any sence unless the singleton is a property which creates the instance in the getter, but even then this would not make sense then the rest of the code would be unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

The technique is called double checking.

The code you pasted, however, is incorrect. You are right, it makes no sense to double check for null value in that way. I would say that correct implementation of double check is following:

```
private static volatile ProcessManager instance = null;

public static ProcessManager getInstance() {
   if (instance == null) {
       synchronized(ProcessManager.class) {
         if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ProcessManager();
         }
      }
   }
   return instance;
}
```

Notice that second null check is synchronized on ProcessManager.class object. It is necessary because getInstance() method is a static one.

Comment: This looks broken to me unless instance is volatile - the first read of instance `if (instance == null)` is not synchronized.